# PHP & MySQL - saving and looping problems

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL I want a user to be able to store multiple names and there meanings in a MySQL database tables named `names` using PHP I will dynamically create form fields with JQuery every time a user clicks on a link so a user can enter 1 to 1,000,000 different names and there meanings which will be stored in a table called `names`.

Since I asked my last question I figured out how to store my values from my form using the `for` loop but every time I loop my values when I add one or more dynamic fields the second form field named `meaning` will not save the value entered also my dynamic form fields keep looping doubling, tripling and so on the entered values into the database it all depends on how many form fields are added dynamically. I was wondering how can I fix these problems?

On a side note I replaced the query with echo's to see the values that are being entered.

Here is the PHP code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "site");
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM names WHERE userID='$userID'");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$meaning = $_POST['meaning'];

if(isset($name['0']) && mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0 && trim($name['0'])!=='' && trim($meaning['0'])!=='') {

for($n = 0; $n < count($name); $n++) {
    for($m = 0; $m < count($meaning); $m++) {
        echo $name[$n] . '<br />';
        echo $meaning[$m] . '<br /><br />';
        break;
    }
}

}

}
?>
```

And here is the HTML code.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<ul>
    <li><label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" /></li>
    <li><label for="meaning">Meaning: </label><input type="text" name="meaning[]" id="meaning" /></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

If needed I will place the JQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the submitted array, things might get clearer:

```
echo('<pre>' . print_r($_POST, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

In case you're still not sure how to tackle the problem:

```
for($index = 0; $index < count($_POST['name']; $index++)
 {
  echo 'name: ' . $_POST['name'][$index] . '<br />';
  echo 'meaning: ' . $_POST['meaning'][$index] . '<br /><br />';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all u use `table` instead of `ul li`

my code is given below, that is running perfectly, u can see [here](http://jsbin.com/emebi)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addMore").click(function(){
    $("#nameline").clone().insertAfter("#nameline").slideDown(500);
    $("#meaningline").clone().insertAfter("#nameline").slideDown(500);
    $("#name:last").val("").focus();
    $("#meaning:last").val("");

});
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="button" name="addMore" id="addMore" value="add">
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="nameline">
        <td><label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="meaningline">
        <td><label for="meaning">Meaning: </label><input type="text" name="meaning[]" id="meaning" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" id="submit" /></td></tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
```

for more information u can refere to [this link](http://my123web.blogspot.com/2009/05/using-jquery-add-row-to-table.html)